# How to make nusoap work on symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I have a webservice (From other company) witch I need to call and use the response data in my controller. I read about nusoap on symfony documentation but I don´t know how to setup it.

Any help?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Be more specific and show us some code.

Comment: that the problem, I downloaded the library, but I don´t know how to setup it to work within my controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the bundle noiselabs/nusoap-bundle.

Add this to composer.json :

```
"require": {
    "noiselabs/nusoap-bundle": "dev-master",
},
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "nusphere/nusoap",
            "version": "0.9.5",
            "dist": {
                "url": "http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/nusoap/nusoap/0.9.5/nusoap-0.9.5.zip",
                "type": "zip"
            },
            "autoload": {
                "classmap": ["lib/"]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

And update :

```
composer.phar update
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy nusoap to your `vendor` or something like folder, than include it and write your Soap related code in your bundle (like `\Company\Bundle\SomeBundle\Webservice`) and call it from your controller.

Personally i choice and recommend `Zend_Soap` for writing web service clients and servers.

Comment: It doen´t matter to me witch client to use. I just want to get the data and use them into my controller. Do you have any example of Zend_Soap with symfony2?

Comment: I haven't. But its very easy to integrate. Include and just implement your business in you bundle.